# file_get_contents add a backup path in-case it don't load

Tags: php

```
<?php
echo "invoices/" . $invoiceN . "/address.txt";
echo file_get_contents("invoices/invoice1/address.txt") or die (file_get_contents("invoices/invoice1/backup.txt"));
?>
```

My aim is to have a backup path in case the first path isn't found.

So in the example above if 'address.txt' doesn't load it will load the backup 'backup.txt'

Comment: ''The function returns the read data or FALSE on failure. This function may return Boolean FALSE, but may also return a non-Boolean value which evaluates to FALSE. Please read the section on Booleans for more information. Use the === operator for testing the return value of this function.'' http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php

Comment: [`die()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.die.php) terminates the script; are you sure this is what you want? `... or die()` is not error handling; it is just a sign you learned from a bad tutorial.

Answer (score 2):

Use `if-else`:-

```
<?php
echo "invoices/" . $invoiceN . "/address.txt";
$data = file_get_contents("invoices/invoice1/address.txt");

if($data){
    echo $data;
}else{
    echo $data = file_get_contents("invoices/invoice1/backup.txt")
}
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

You could check if the file exists before trying to read it...

```
$fileName = "invoices/" . $invoiceN . "/address.txt";
if ( !file_exists($filename))   {
    $fileName = "invoices/" . $invoiceN . "/backup.txt";
}
echo file_get_contents($fileName);
```